# Next steps with accessing an Excel table from one sheet into another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, dropdownlist

I've done it once before, using a web tutorial that I cannot locate again, but now I'm trying to it again and I'd appreciate some insight in terms of “next steps” and where I am going wrong.

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with two sheets, a *main sheet* and a *data sources* sheet. Within *data sources*, I have a named table, `_010FieldTemplatesExamples`, that contains **two** MARC field examples using pre-2001 and post-2001 formatting for the LC standard number. The cell reference is set up in **Names Manager** and I've set up the data validation using a list.

However, the problem I'm having is I **cannot** get this to correctly appear as a drop-down box in the *main* sheet in cell `G2`, which is the cell under the “Field Example(s) and Template(s)” column for the **010** row/record (a.k.a. row 2).

I'd appreciate it if someone would help me “complete the steps” – I think I'm about 70% there (maybe more!) but am getting hung up here.

Comment: Would people quit downvoting this rather well thought out, excellent question? I'm really looking for a response here. Thanks! :)

Comment: (1) Your title didn’t seem to match your question body, so I changed it.  If you really mean “inserting an Excel table”, please [edit] your question to clarify.  (2) You might get a better reception if you described what you’ve tried.  (Patting yourself on the back will only hurt your arm.)  (3) I don’t know what MARC, pre-2001 formatting, post-2001 formatting and the LC standard number mean.  If they are really relevant to the question, explain, or at least provide a reference link.  If they’re not really relevant to the question, find a more relatable way to describe your problem. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) There’s no point in telling us the row and column where you’re having the problem if you don’t show us the spreadsheet. (Even then, I’m not sure it would help.)  … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Scott, for your reply, and for editing my post's title. You're right; the details on MARC pre- and post-2001 formatting and LC standard numbers are irrelevant information. My apologies. I have a habit of including extraneous information. For what it's worth, I'm a library technician student and MARC refers to MAchine Readable Coding whereas LC standard number simply refers to the Library of Congress classification number. ;)

Anyway, I thought I should answer my own question. Since I posted this, I've taken a course in Excel, Access, Word, and PowerPoint, that was required for my program and for anyone interested, what I simply needed to do, I believe, was reference the name of the sheet and cell like this:

```
!'Name of Sheet!A1:D10 (for an unnamed range)
```

or

```
!'Name of Sheet'!NamedRange (for a named range)
```

Right?

Cheers,
Doug